# How to add Data to SQLite offline database table and display it on listView Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, sql, visual-studio, xamarin

I am doing a Weather app project in Xamarin.Forms. After successfully adding users to the database and validating the existing ones on "log in", now I am struggling with adding a town(with 3 variables) inside SQLite database and then displaying the information in ListView on a content page.
The problem is that when I click the "weather" button there is nothing displayed in the ListView and also the second catch is triggered - Temp = "Unable to get Weather";

Let's begin with my Model for the Town/s:

```
public class Town
{       
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string TownName { get; set; }
    public string Temp { get; set; }
    public string searchTime { get; set; }

    public Town() { }
}
```

After creating this simple class, I am implementing a controller class for taking care of the Town data:

```
SQLiteConnection database;

    public SearchHistoryDataController()
    {

        database = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().GetConnection();

        database.CreateTable<Town>();

    }

    IEnumerable<Town> orderItemCollection;
    public IEnumerable<Town> OrderItemCollection
    {
        get
        {
            if (orderItemCollection == null)
                orderItemCollection = GetTowns();
            return orderItemCollection;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Town> GetTowns()
    {
        // Changing the database table items as ObservableCollection
        var table = (from i in database.Table<Town>() select i);
        ObservableCollection<Town> TownList = new ObservableCollection<Town>();
        foreach (var town in table)
        {
            TownList.Add(new Town()
            {
                ID = town.ID,
                TownName = town.TownName,
                Temp = town.Temp,
                searchTime = town.searchTime
            });
        }
        return TownList;
    }

    public Town GetTown(int id)
    {

        return database.Table<Town>().FirstOrDefault(t => t.ID == id);

    }


    public void DeleteTown(int id)
    {

        database.Delete<Town>(id);

    }

    public string AddTown(Town town)
    {
        var data = database.Table<Town>();
        var d1 = data.Where(x => x.TownName == town.TownName && x.searchTime == town.searchTime).FirstOrDefault();

        if (d1 == null)
        {           

            database.Insert(town);

            return "Successfully Added";

        }
        else
        {
            return "Invalid Town id Exist";
        }
    }
```

From here the last two things are: 
Creating a Town, insert some information, storing the Town in the database and this is done in command whenever the "Show weather" button is clicked. There is the code:

```
                 //Get weather information for the Weather view
            Temp = $"{weatherRoot?.MainWeather?.Temperature ?? 0}°C";
            Condition = $"{weatherRoot?.Weather?[0]?.Description ?? string.Empty}";
            Name = $"{weatherRoot.Name}, {weatherRoot.System.Country}";
            Humidity = $"{weatherRoot.MainWeather.Humidity}%";
            Pressure = $"{weatherRoot.MainWeather.Pressure} hpa";
            Clouds = $"{weatherRoot.Clouds.CloudinessPercent}%";
            Wind = $"{weatherRoot.Wind.Speed} m/s";


            town.TownName = $"{weatherRoot.Name}";
            town.Temp = Temp;
            town.searchTime = DateTime.Parse(weatherRoot.Date).ToLocalTime().ToString("g");;

            //history database push               
            try
            {
                SearchHistoryDataController searchHistoryDataController = new SearchHistoryDataController();
                var returnvalue = searchHistoryDataController.AddTown(town);

                if (returnvalue == "Sucessfully Added")
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Success");

                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Fail");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception es)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(es.Message);
            }


            await TextToSpeech.SpeakAsync(Temp + " " + Condition);
            IsBusy = false;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Temp = "Unable to get Weather";
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            IsBusy = false;
        }
    }
```

The final - XAML file which is structured like this:

```
 <Grid>
        <Image HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Aspect="AspectFill" Source="gradientBack.png"/>
        <StackLayout Padding="10" Spacing="10">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="20" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Start" Margin="5,20">
                <Label Text="Search History" FontSize="20" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
            </StackLayout>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding OrderItemCollection}"
              HasUnevenRows="True"
              CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
              IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
              RefreshCommand="{Binding GetWeatherCommand}"
              IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}"
              RowHeight="66"
              x:Name="ListViewTide">
                <ListView.SeparatorColor>
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Color" iOS="Transparent"/>
                </ListView.SeparatorColor>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Frame BackgroundColor="White" BorderColor="#F0F0F0" Padding="5" Margin="0,0,0,5" HasShadow="False">
                                <Grid HeightRequest="50" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding DisplayTide}" TextColor="#800080" FontSize="15"
                                           FontAttributes="Bold"
                                           Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}"/>
                                    <StackLayout Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="20,0" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Center">
                                        <Label Text="{Binding DisplayTime}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="15" FontAttributes="None" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </Grid>
                            </Frame>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
```

The idea is to automatically update the History list when the "weather" button is clicked. The history will store the name of the town in the text field, the exact time and also the temperature.
The list won't be used for anything else and it is a tab.

Thank you very much!

Comment: what is the actual Exception that is causing the "unable to get weather" message?

Comment: It is about weather information. It works fine and if I remove the part about town database this Exception is not triggered.

Comment: Jason, could you calm down a bit. There is no exception message because there is no existing error. If there was an exception message which will help you solve the issue, I will definitely share it. I fixed the problem already. BR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did solve the problem. First issue was with this line: `town.searchTime = DateTime.Parse(weatherRoot.Date).ToLocalTime().ToString("g");`

It was causing the command to fail because this date variable wasn't accessible. I fixed it with: `town.searchTime = DateTime.Now.ToString();`

Next - how to display data saved in the SQLite database:

Inserting Town into the database and then polling it out and store it under TownList:

```
town.TownName = $"{weatherRoot.Name}";
                town.Temp = Temp;
                town.searchTime = DateTime.Now.ToString();

                //history database push               
                try
                {      
                    var returnvalue = searchHistoryDataController.AddTown(town);

                    if (returnvalue == "Sucessfully Added")
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine("Success");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Fail");
                    }                
                }
                catch (Exception es)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(es.Message);
                }

                TownList = searchHistoryDataController.OrderItemCollection;
```

Last but not least the XAML and the SearchHistoryController:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding TownList}"
              x:Name="ListViewTide">
                <ListView.SeparatorColor>
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Color" iOS="Transparent"/>
                </ListView.SeparatorColor>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Frame BackgroundColor="White" BorderColor="#F0F0F0" Padding="5" Margin="0,0,0,5" HasShadow="False">
                                <Grid HeightRequest="50" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding TownName}" TextColor="#757575" FontSize="13" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="20,0"/>
                                    <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding searchTime}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="10" FontAttributes="None" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                                    <StackLayout Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="20,0" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Center">
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Temp}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="25" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </Grid>
                            </Frame>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

The method for pulling the info from SQL to List:

```
 IEnumerable<Town> orderItemCollection;
        public IEnumerable<Town> OrderItemCollection
        {
            get
            {
                if (orderItemCollection == null)
                    orderItemCollection = GetTowns();
                return orderItemCollection;
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<Town> GetTowns()
        {
            // Changing the database table items as ObservableCollection
            var table = (from i in database.Table<Town>() select i);
            ObservableCollection<Town> TownList = new ObservableCollection<Town>();
            foreach (var town in table)
            {
                TownList.Add(new Town()
                {
                    ID = town.ID,
                    TownName = town.TownName,
                    Temp = town.Temp,
                    searchTime = town.searchTime
                });
            }
            return TownList;
        }
```

And just to remind everyone that the Model for your object, if it will be stored in SQL, always include `AutoIncrement` :

```
[PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int ID { get; set; }
```

Hope this will help someone. :)

Comment: Could you please mark your reply as an answer so that others who has similar question could get help from your answer? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I am about to do that. There is a restriction to mark your own response as an answer and I have to wait 24 hours.